# Why is this program going this way? C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Hello stackOverflowers! Can someone explain why when I charge an array from 1 to 10 the output says the minimun even is 1 an the maximun even is 10, and when I start the array from 10 to 1 the output is the minimun is 2 and the maximun is 10. I think the nested if sequence is correct, because the counter shows  correct even and correct odd numbers, but Ithink I'missing something...
The program should output the minimun and the maximun even number inside the array.

Thanks for the answer!

```
/*EVEN MAX AND MIN POINTER FUNCTION*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXARRAY 100

typedef int ArrayTable[MAXARRAY];

void chargeArray(ArrayTable,int);
void maxMinEven(const ArrayTable, int, int *, int *,int *,int *);

int main(){
    ArrayTable intTable;
    int maxim,minim;
    int contEven=0,contOdd=0;
    int n=10;

    printf("Input %d integer number:\n",n);
    chargeArray(intTable,n);
    maxMinEven(intTable,n,&minim,&maxim,&contEven,&contOdd);
    printf("The minimun even of the %d number is %d and the maximun %d. Even     %d Odd %d\n",n,minim,maxim,contEven,contOdd);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void chargeArray(ArrayTable t,int n){
    int i=0;
    int number;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){       
        scanf("%d",&number);
        t[i]=number;
    }
}

void maxMinEven(const ArrayTable t, int n, int *min, int *max,int      *contEven,int *contOdd){
    int i;
    *min=t[0];
    *max=t[0];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){       
        if(t[i]%2==0){  
            (*contEven)++;/*incremento el contenido de la direccion de    memoria de contPar*/

            if(t[i]>*max)
                *max=t[i];  

            if(t[i]<*min)       
                *min=t[i];      

}else{
            (*contOdd)++;/*incremento el contenido de la direccion de memoria de   contImp*/
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Time to learn how nto debug.

Comment: Please be more explicit, it's not so obviously for me. Where is the error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your title does not reflect what you are asking, please choose a better title.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that way next time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At these two lines:

```
*min=t[0];
*max=t[0];
```

Your code assumes that `t[0]` is an even number. However, that's not necessarily true.

One fix would be:

```
*min = INT_MIN;
*max = INT_MAX;
```

Comment: Ok, and how and where I initialize INT_MIN and INT_MAX? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the min to be equal to the first element of the array, regardless if it is even or not.

```
*min=t[0];
```

Inside the loop you compare the values to this minimum. 
You get this result, since 1 is smaller than any other even number in your array.

Hope I helped,

Comment: Yes, you Helped, but how is the initialisation in this case?

Comment: If you have valid and invalid value (e.g. only positive numbers) you can use a value outside the range (or INT_MIN INT_Max as mentioned by Bill Tynch). If not, use a flag. Either way, you should consider what is your return value in case non of the numbers is even.

Comment: Ok, I undsertand. I've done that way and it works fine.